# How to use the li-name as link in the li-item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

Hye,

Ive got a javascript function to get all the ''-items on the current page. This works correctly, but i want to use the output-name as link for each li item. Here a example:

One of the li items has the name: 'Scalder'. It looks like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Scalder</li>
  <li>other-item</li>
  <li>other-item</li>
  <li>other-item</li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the result like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li id='Scalder'>Scalder</li>
  <li id='other-item'>other-item</li>
  <li id='other-item'>other-item</li>
  <li id='other-item'>other-item</li>
</ul>
```

Each item also has to set the link for the li-item.

My current code to build this is:

```js
var mainEl = document.getElementsByTagName("main"),
      //Because we only have one main tag, from the previous
      //collection we chose the first elemnt
      //From that element we create a collection with all the h2 inside
      headingsEls = mainEl[0].getElementsByTagName("output"),
      //collection of elements with "aside" tag
      asideEl = document.getElementsByTagName("aside"),
      //We create the ul that wil hold the list
      ulEl = document.createElement("ul")

    //Go throw the h2 collection and for each element we create a new li element,
    //we pass to it the text content and we put it on the ul
    for( var i = 0; i < headingsEls.length; i++ ) {

        var liEl = document.createElement("li")

        liEl.textContent = headingsEls[i].textContent
        ulEl.appendChild(liEl)
    }

    //the new ul with the list is appended!
    asideEl[0].appendChild(ulEl)
```

Hopefully i'm clear about my wishes. Have a good day!

Comment: So you want to set the `id` of each `li` to match its text? Note that you could esily end up with duplicates here, and any spaces in the text will mean the `id` is invalid. I'd ask why you feel the need to do this, though, as setting id at runtime is a smal code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **jQuery**:

Use `$(this).attr('id',$(this).text());` for each of the `<li>` elements:

```js
$('ul li').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('id',$(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Scalder</li>
  <li>other-item1</li>
  <li>other-item2</li>
  <li>other-item3</li>
</ul>
```

Using **JavaScript**:

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
for(var i=0; i<elem.length; i++){
  elem[i].setAttribute('id',elem[i].innerText);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Scalder</li>
  <li>other-item1</li>
  <li>other-item2</li>
  <li>other-item3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Writing a function which returns the html based on the output

---

> Code

```
function convertlistTolinks(){
    let html = "";  
    html +=`<ul>`
    for(var i = 0; i < headingsEls.length; i++ ){
      html +=`<li id=`${headingsEls[i].element}`><a>`${headingsEls[i].element}`</a</li>`    
    }
    html +=`</ul>`;
   //appending the dynamic list to the parent element in the dom
    document.getElementById("parentElement").appendChild(html)
```

}